# $window.location.href doesn't reload whole page in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a code like this to create an account and than i want to validate (with some specifics functions) and after that redirect to the main page.

```
$scope.createAccount = function(cad) {
    $http.post('dist/func.php?action=createAccount', cad).then(
        function(res) {
            //..more functions
            $window.location.href = '/adm';
        },
        function(err) {
            Notification.error(feedbackError);
        }
    );
};
```

The problem is, when the user arrive in the new page, the `mainCtrl` is not running (the page is not fully reloading) so i can't get essential data for this new user.

I saw some other similar questions, but all of them says we should use $window.location.href instead of $location to get a full page reload. But until now, i had no success with it.

How can i solve it?

Comment: did you inject it on your controller?

Comment: What do you meant the `mainCtrl` is not running? Are you saying that `$window.location.href` does nothing?

Comment: The `$window.location.href` is refirecting to the correct page. But, on this page, I have a main controller, which is called on the body tag, so, everytime i reload or access the page for the first time, this controller is going to initiate. When i use `$window.location.href` this controller does nothing, like it was already in use.

Comment: could you please try `$window.open('/adm', '_self');`

Comment: `_self` was the way to go. It was returning to the server root. Thanks! Even with a simple `<a href="adm">` the result was the same until i used `_self`. But i didn't knew it could be applied to `window.location` as well.